# Enabling Yosemite's Dark mode through Terminal or Applescript OSX 10.1

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, settings, osx-yosemite

Is there any way to turn on Yosemite's Dark Mode through Shell Script (Terminal) or Applescript? I have tried:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleInterfaceTheme Dark
```

but it does not work.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I did it in Applescript like this:

```
do shell script ("sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist _HIEnableThemeSwitchHotKey -bool true") with administrator privileges
tell application "Finder" to activate
delay 0.2
tell application "System Events"
key code "17" using {option down, control down, command down}     #Option+Control+Command+T
end tell
```

Comment: What does that key combination do? I can't see it from any of the Finder menu items.

Comment: It is hidden, you have to enable it by doing `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist _HIEnableThemeSwitchHotKey -bool true` in terminal. It enables Yosemite's Dark Mode

Answer (score 2):

I made a command-line app for this exact purpose: [`dark-mode`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dark-mode).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restart some services to refresh it too:

sudo killall Dock;killall SystemUIServer;killall Finder;killall cfprefsd